# sencha touch / phonegap - database

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch

I am developing an app that will need to list countries and then cities. This could obviously be quite a large database - what is the best way to store this data?

I don't want to use a remote database as I would like the app to be useable offline.

I'm open to any format (xml, javascript array, cvs etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Sencha Touch's Model and Store functionality to read a json web service or file and make it available to your views.

```
Ext.regModel('Product', {
    fields: [
        {name: "id", type: "int"},
        {name: "pid", type: "int"},
        {name: "type", type: "string"},
        {name: "status", type: "string"},
        {name: "title", type: "string"},
        {name: "content", type: "auto"},
        {name: "date", type: "string"},
        {name: "modified", type: "string"}  
    ]
});


MVCApp.ProductStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Product',
    autoLoad: true,
    storeId: 'ProductStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        id: 'ProductStore',
        url: 'data/nestedProducts.json',
        reader: {
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a local json file and access this one with a sencha touch store (Ext.data.Store).